# Why is my string length being printed as zero?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


    //function for taking in a line
    string line ;
    auto line_size = line.size();

    while (getline(cin, line))
        if (!line.empty())
        {
            cout << line_size << endl;
            cout << line << endl;
        }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't the `line_size` printing the correct size when i give in some input?

Comment: Why do you expect it to print correct size?

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand how C++ variables work. `auto line_size = line.size();` doesn't mean that from now onwards, every time you say `line_size` the C++ compiler will understand you to be talking about `line.size()`. It means that `line.size()` will be called once to get a number, and that number will be assigned to the variable `line_size`. Since `line` is an empty string at the point you do this, the number is `0`.

Comment: @SteveJessop that was my misinterpretation so when the member function is called at that instance the size of the string is being set not always being updated with the value. Adding this ' line_size = line.size(); '
 into the loop will fix it. Thanks

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know endl is a manipulator and flushes the stream but why should't I? I have seen a lot of people argue about this.

Comment: @psraganvesh - because building in unnecessary overhead is a bad habit. There's simply no good reason to add the overhead of a flush on every line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are capturing the size of the line before you get any input.  This means `line_size` will always be 0 as that is the size of the empty string.  Instead of capturing the size you can just change the loop to

```
cout << line.size() << endl; // always gets the size of the current line
cout << line << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you create an empty `string` which obviously has a size of `0` and store the `0` in a variable `line_size`

```
string line ;
auto line_size = line.size();
```

Here you get a new line

```
while (getline(cin, line))
```

and here you print the value of `line_size`, that is still `0`

```
cout << line_size << endl;
```

`line_size` doesn't get updated when `line` is updated. To get the current line size print :

```
cout << line.size() << endl;
```